# Node.js: how to read user select choice and serve file contents in textarea upon submit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-applications, web

Node.js beginner here so bear with me. Maybe I'm a bit slow but I cannot figure out how to read a select box choice after a user submits it and then take some action based on what the choice is. Basically, I have something like this in the HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="100">
</textarea>
```

Now all I want to do is when a user chooses Volvo, and submits, a file (volvo.txt) is read from the server and the contents of that file are included in the textarea. Whether the user is redirected to some /submit sub-site and the same stuff is shows as on the start page is irrelevant. It seems like this should be an easy task but maybe I'm missing something obvious. Thanks for your help!

Edit: forgot to mention that I'm looking for a server-side solution that utilizes Node.js.

Comment: are you interested in client-side code or server-side? And are you using any client-side library?

Comment: Server-side please. Specifically trying to do this using Node.js. I guess I should add that to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a  tag around your select and all elements need a `name` attribute. Then you can process the data on node.js. I recommend starting with [express.js](http://expressjs.com). [This guide](http://www.hacksparrow.com/form-handling-processing-in-express-js.html) explains step-by-step how it works.

To read a file and respond to the client, see [this article from nodejitsu](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs).

Comment: What tag around the select? I'm guessing just the <option> and <textarea> elements need a "name"? Also, is there any way to do this w/o Express.js? I get the 'how to read a file' but how do you inject the contents into the textarea?

Comment: `<select name="car">` will give you the option in the post body. If you have no experience with node.js I STRONGLY recommend express.js, it helps a lot handling request and response. If you understand node.js better, you can do it without express.

Comment: A ha! Got it to work finally using Express. Thanks for the suggestions!